# change scroll height

Tags: javascript, css

Is possible to change scrollbar height? I need to set it to 80% of container height and put it to the to bottom? It's possible to make it with scrollbar.js library?

Something like this,  [link to img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oHJ9.png)

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Isn't this actively making the UX worse?

Comment: Ask guy who made graphics project :D

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp

Comment: Is not supported by all browsers

Answer (score 0):

You can user [Jquery scrollbar plugin](http://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/) this plugin support all browsers (NO IE8)

also u can use custom css but i dont suggest to u : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp